# Simultaneous Equations $a^2 - b^2 = -16$ and $2ab = 30$

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

I need help solving these simultaneous equations:

$$a^2 - b^2 = -16$$
$$2ab = 30$$

Comment: What have you tried do far?

Comment: Any thoughts?  $\quad $

Answer (score 0):

After dividing by $2$ we get $$b=\frac{15}{a}$$ plugging this in the first equation we get
$$a^2-\left(\frac{15}{a}\right)^2=-16$$
Can you proceed?
After multiplying by $$a^2$$ we obtain
$$a^4+16a^2-225=0$$ now substitute $$a^2=t$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You may use the *polarisation identity*:
$$xy=\tfrac14\bigl( (x+y)^2-(x-y)^2\bigr)$$
to deduce $a^2+b^2$. This will ultimately produce a linear systemin $a^2$ and $b^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Oftentimes this particular type of simultaneous equations (which often arise when finding square roots of complex numbers for example) have "nice" whole number solutions. It's a good idea to *look for these whole number solutions first by inspection* before doing any long calculations.

In this case, we know from the second equation that $ab = 15$. So if we want whole number solutions, *we should try with $a,b$ being **factors of 15*** (so just $\{1,15\}$ or $\{ 3,5\}$ here (or negatives of these)). By looking at the first equation, we see by inspection that $a=3,b=5$ will work (since $3\times 5=15$ and $3^2-5^2=9-25=-16$). Hence we obtain the solution $a=3,b=5$. Also $a=-3,b=-5$ will be the other solution.

(If this question was asking for finding the square root of a complex number, once you found one solution, say $a=3,b=5$, you could immediately write down that the square roots are $\pm(3+5i)$. If the question just came on it's own, you would probably need to provide explanation of why these are all the solutions.)

Answer (score 0):

I looked for an **integer** solution:

$$2ab = 30 \implies ab = 15$$
$$a\  and\ b \in  \{\pm1,\pm3,\pm5,\pm15\}$$
Trial and error  yields $$\{a,b\}\ = \{-3,-5\}\ or\ \{3,5\}$$